# Modal dialog not closing by default close x button

Tags: javascript, html

I have following modal dialog coding,but when i click [X],the dialog doesn't closed. I invoke the dialog from button and the JavaScript function as follow;

```
$('#apply_Compensation_Leave').show();
```

Modal code

```
<div class="modal" id="apply_Compensation_Leave" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="messageModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content"> 
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  aria-hidden="true"><li class="fa fa-times"/></button>
        <h3 style="font-size: 17px;">Apply Leave</h3>
    </div>
<div class="modal-body">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Did i miss anything?

Adding Javascript file..all javascript functions in seperate  .js file.

```
EmpcompensationAdapter.method('getActionButtonsHtml', function(id,data) {
    var html = "";
    html = '<div style="width:80px;"><img class="tableActionButton" src="BASE_URL/apply.png" style="cursor:pointer;" rel="tooltip" title="Apply Leave" onclick="modJs.applyleaves();return false;"></img></div>';
    return html;
});

EmpcompensationAdapter.method('applyleaves', function() {

    $('#apply_Compensation_Leave').show();

});

EmpcompensationAdapter.method('showLeaveView', function() {
    $('#apply_Compensation_Leave').hide();  
});
```

When i click Back button, by calling the function showLeaveView();

Comment: From JQuery try to use $('#apply_Compensation_Leave').modal('show'); to open the modal.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from adding `$('#apply_Compensation_Leave').modal('show');`, you need to change your HTML also. `<li>` tag should not be put without `<ul>`. **It's not valid markup at all.** Try putting `&times;` in your `button` HTML.

```
<div class="modal" id="apply_Compensation_Leave" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="messageModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content"> 
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 style="font-size: 17px;">Apply Leave</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
</div>
</div>
</div>
 </div>
```

Here is a [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Xwg4AWQ3fE)

Or you can provide valid markup like this `<ul><li class="fa fa-times"></li></ul>`

Here is a [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/5lJZWPmG6E) with the valid markup.

Comment: I tried your code. But it doesn't get closed. Just i copied the whole code and pasted it. May be the reason of javascript. im opening the modal,by pressing the button and i having click function for the button. Just i added that code in my question for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap Modal is invoked by `$('#apply_Compensation_Leave').modal('show');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/DTcHh/16184/).

You are opening your `modal` using JS.

You can use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/DTcHh/16181/).But this has wrong markup as @Alorika Mentioned

```
    <div class="modal" id="apply_Compensation_Leave" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="messageModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">

        </button>
        <h3 style="font-size: 17px;">Apply Leave</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#apply_Compensation_Leave').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout :

```
  <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">  <center>Title here </center> </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...Body here...
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" id="Okbtn" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"> CANCEL</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```